# Using parentheses in CodeIgniter ActiveRecord where() method

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How to make this query below with **CodeIgniter database ActiveRecord**?

```sql
  SELECT *
  FROM `request`
  WHERE (`requestedID` = 42 OR `challengerID` = 42)
  AND (`requApprove` = 1 AND `challApprove` = 1);
```

I tried many patterns.. but it didn't work.
I can't understand how to use CI AR methods to build this query which contains parentheses.

Comment: The error you're getting would be?

Comment: not output..jst null..

Comment: go with CI type querries

Comment: I think no error in querry. You check the values in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CI doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

> `$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.

So, the needed AR methods would be:

```php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('request');
$this->db->where('(requestedID = 42 OR challengerID = 42)', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->where('(requApprove = 1 AND challApprove = 1)', NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get();
```